# Refactoring class with a lot of Switches and ifs

Tags: java, enums, functional-programming

I'm dealing with a class which has a lot of switches and ifs. I would like to hear from somebody any advice in order to get the best refactoring. I was thinking if it is possible to use functional programming to avoid to much ifs.

The class has two enums and each enum have at least 8 possibilities. So, the logic is based on returning an enum depending on switch-if-else structures.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no silver-bullet recipe here. Show the code to unleash the community's imagination.

Comment: Maybe you can use the strategy pattern(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) where each if-else is a specific strategy which may be implemented via Enum.

Comment: And in that sense: if you are really going to show code to receive comments on it .. why not turn to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Please post sample code, so we can work with that as a starting point. In general, without seeing your code, I can only tell you that the state pattern is used to avoid conditional logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to give definite answer without a code, but one of the main refactoring methods is [Replacing Conditional with Polymorphism](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism).

**Edit**: [Java example from Martin Fowler](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html)

Answer (score 0):

First in OO ifs and switches can often be replaced by *overriden* methods. Either in the enum as method, or using an EnumMap. In java 8 you might add a lambda to the enum constructor too.

More important I think so many cases seem to indicate that **business logic** is written out in code. That you can do also in *declarative* style, in XML for instance. That in general simplifies the structure and is more sure.

Answer (score 0):

If possible move the multiple functionalities in the branching to separate classes with a common interface to it.  Then try to replace all the static branching with a dynamic double dispatch.

Say for eg:

```
  int a = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt(); // Any number can be given here.
  if(a % 5 == 0) {
    performMultiple5Operation(a);
  } else if(a % 6 == 0) {
    performMultiple6Operation(a);
  } else if(a % 7 == 0) {
    performMultiple7Operation(a);
  } else if(isPrime(a)) {
    performPrimeOperation(a);
  }
```

replace this static branching with a dynamic double dispatch way as below:

```
public class DynamicDoubleDispatcher {
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.close();
        NumericOperator no = new NumericOperator(new Performer[] { new Multiple5Performer(), new Multiple6Performer(),
                new Multiple7Performer(), new PrimePerformer()});
        no.operate(a);  // The performs the right operation based on the input value of a.
    }
}

interface Performer {
    public boolean perform(int a);
}

class NumericOperator {
    private List<Performer> performers = new ArrayList<>();

    public NumericOperator(Performer[] arrPerformers) {
        this.performers = Arrays.asList(arrPerformers);
    }

    public void operate(int a) {
        for (Performer performer : performers) {
            if (performer.perform(a))
                break;
        }
    }
}

class Multiple5Performer implements Performer {
    public boolean perform(int a) {
        boolean isPerformed = false;
        if (a % 5 == 0) {
            isPerformed = true;
            performMultiple5Operation();
        }
        return isPerformed;
    }

    private void performMultiple5Operation() {
        // TODO: Do the multiple 5 Operation
    }
}

class Multiple6Performer implements Performer {
    public boolean perform(int a) {
        boolean isPerformed = false;
        if (a % 6 == 0) {
            isPerformed = true;
            performMultiple6Operation();
        }
        return isPerformed;
    }

    private void performMultiple6Operation() {
        // TODO: Do the multiple 6 Operation

    }
}

class Multiple7Performer implements Performer {
    public boolean perform(int a) {
        boolean isPerformed = false;
        if (a % 7 == 0) {
            isPerformed = true;
            performMultiple7Operation();
        }
        return isPerformed;
    }

    private void performMultiple7Operation() {
        // TODO: Do the multiple 7 Operation

    }
}

class PrimePerformer implements Performer {
    public boolean perform(int a) {
        boolean isPerformed = false;
        if (isPrime(a)) {
            isPerformed = true;
            performPrimeOperation();
        }
        return isPerformed;
    }

    private void performPrimeOperation() {
        // TODO: Do the prime Operation
    }

    private boolean isPrime(int a) {
        boolean isPrime = false;
        // TODO: check a is prime or not
        return isPrime;
    }
}
```

You will be sacrificing on performance a bit, but it helps in having an extendable design for future use also with specific and limited modification to the existing classes.